# Конвертация большого числа из char в int

Tags: c

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно открыть файл и рассортировать его содержимое по структуре. (Cтруктура Base)
В файле лежит нечто подобное:
Ivan Ivanov 13122016 79811111111
Его содержимое парсится в массив типа char (Collection). Данные разделены пробелами (' '), а строки - '\n'
В общем, мой алгоритм не работает. (символы криво, но сохраняются в структуру, а числа - нет) И я не смог его пофиксить.
Можете помочь его исправить? Спасибо.
Код:

```
char Collection[200];
char Temp[2]; Temp[1] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        z++;
        if (Collection[i] == '\n' || Collection[i] == '\0')
            break;
        if (Collection[i] == ' ') {
            start = i;
            for (int j = start + 1; j <= 200; ++j) {
                if (Collection[j] == ' ') {
                    end = j; break;
                }
            }

            for (int j = start + 1; j <= end - 1; ++j) {
                if (z == 0)
                    Base[z].Name[j] = Collection[j];
                if (z == 1)
                    Base[z].Surname[j] = Collection[j];
                if (z == 2) {
                    Temp[1] = Collection[j];
                    if (end - j - 1 != 0) {
                        Digit = Digit + atoi(Temp) * 10 ^ (end - j - 1);
                        printf("%d", Digit);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Digit = Digit + atoi(Temp);
                        Base[0].Date = Digit;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `scanf` и не мучайтесь... Например:

```
struct Data {
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int date;
    long long num;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s[] = "Ivan Ivanov 13122016 79811111111";
    struct Data d;
    sscanf(s,"%49s %49s %d %lld",d.name,d.surname,&d.date,&d.num);

    printf("%s %s - %d -- %lld\n",d.name,d.surname,d.date,d.num);
}
```

У вас не описаны структуры, так что я написал своё.